# formatting value in a string to have a decimal separator

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting

if i have a value stored like:

```
long long unsigned x=1000000000000;
```

i'd like to have a

```
NSString *strx=[...];
```

so if i use NSLog or bitmapfont for this integer, what is displayed will be:

```
1,000,000,000,000
```

do exists this king od formatter?
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSNumberFormatter` is the class to go to. For example:

```
long num = 1000000000;
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.positiveFormat = @"#,###";
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLong:num]]);
```

prints out `1,000,000,000`. There are a lot of predefined styles and further options that can be explored:

- NSNumberFormatter reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- Format patterns: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Number_Format_Patterns